# If / Else logic and custom variables

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to run some `if / else` logic in my pipelines using [expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops).

```yaml
trigger:
  - dev
  - qa
  - main
  - test/*

resources:
  - repo: self

variables:
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
  # We get rid off the 'refs/heads/' to isolate the branch name and deduce the environment we're running on.
  # If running on 'main' branch, env value will be 'prod'.
  env: $[replace(replace(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main', 'prod'), 'refs/heads/', '')]

stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build stage
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)
        steps:
          - script: | # this below block works as expected            
              if [[ $(env) == "dev" ]] ; then
                echo "dev"
              elif [[ $(env) == "qa" ]] ; then
                echo "qa"
              elif [[ $(env) == "prod" ]] ; then
                echo "prod"
              else 
                echo "We are running on an unmanaged branch"
              fi
            displayName: Test 1        
          - script: echo "Deploying to $(env)"
            ${{ if in(variables['env'], 'prod', 'qa', 'dev') }}:
              displayName:  Deploy to a managed environment # we never get there
            ${{ else }}:
              displayName: Deploy to an unmanaged environment # always here
```

I have tried both `variables['env']` and `variables.env` syntax as [stated here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#variables) but no more luck.

Any idea why my implementation doesn't work ? I think I could be using the system's `variables['Build.SourceBranchName']` into that `if/else` statement but I would like to understand what's wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It because the  `$[replace(replace(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main', 'prod'), 'refs/heads/', '')]` is a **runtime** expression, and the `displayName` is evaluated **before** the runtime - when the YAML file is compiled into a plan.

This is why `Build.SourceBranchName` will work for you, because this variable is  evaluated before the runtime.

Comment: I have tried with this syntax - no much luck : `${{ if in(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'refs/heads/main','refs/heads/qa','refs/heads/dev' ) }}:`

Comment: Moreover from I read, this Template expression syntax should work as its proceed before runtime, but it didn't give me the expected results when I tried it. Any chance you could provide me with an example ? Thanks :)  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#template-expression-syntax

Comment: the `SourceBranchName` it without `refs/heads`, remove them..